# How to preload threads in a thread pool to improve C# application performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I'm writing an application which needs to process up to 10000 data per second. I've started to use the managed threadpool and it all works fine. However, my problem is, the initial start of the program seems a little sluggish which I've found out is due to the initial thread creation.

Is there a way to preload threads in a threadpool in C#?

this is how I'm using the ThreadpooL:

```
if (utilities.DatabaseType == "SQLite")
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(InsertDataOnSeparateThread, new object[] { Sample, T });
}
```

Comment: How did you detect that thread creation was a performance bottleneck?
Over what period does the sluggishness occur, and what's going on in your app at that time?

Comment: SQLite does not support multiple concurrent writers.  You're artificially creating contention on the database. Instead of queueing up inserts on multiple separate threads, do it all on one thread.  If you have lots of threads creating data to insert, use a producer/consumer queue so lots of threads create data and one thread inserts it.